# How to handle errors with firebase admin sdk for Go?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication

New to Go and trying to understand how to access the error details. I've already created a user, and now I'm expecting to get a "email-already-exists" error:

```
    fbUser, err := s.auth.CreateUser(ctx, fbUserParams)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("[email] already exists") // <- it could be any other error, and I want to be able to handle it
    }
```

Here's what I see in my debugger:

[image]

How can I handle the error so that I can get the Code from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best option you have is using the `Errors.As` function. You can learn more about it at here: https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As
The error returned by Google Firebase is of type `FirebaseError` that involves two properties: `Code` and `String`. You can try with the following code snippet:

```golang
fbUser, err := s.auth.CreateUser(ctx, fbUserParams)
if err != nil {
    var firebaseErr *FirebaseError
    if errors.As(err, &firebaseErr) {
        // here you can access "Code" and "String"
    } else {
        return nil, errors.New("[email] already exists")
    }
}
```

Thanks to this code you should be able to manage what you need. Pay attention to import correctly the package that provides the type `FirebaseError`. Maybe read something on the Firebase documentation first.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it seems that `FirebaseError` is not accessible - https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/internal

Comment: Ohh I figured it out!!! First mistake: I was using `v3` of the sdk. I updated to `v4`. In `v4` there is this: https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/errorutils#pkg-overview

Now I can use those methods from that package and check what went wrong!!!

Comment: Thanks again I learn of errors.As

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but today I found myself in the same situation. Here is what you can do.

Some context: [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/error-handling#go) states that

> The Go Admin SDK provides an errorutils package which contains a
> series of functions that allow testing for error codes

There are functions like `IsInvalidArgument(err error)` or `IsNotFound(err error)`, all returning a bool value.

The same document states that

> APIs that expose service error codes provide API-specific error
> checking functions in the corresponding packages.

In your case it's the auth package, so you will consider the functions whose names begin with `auth.Is...`. For example `auth.IsCertificateFetchFailed(err)` or `auth.IsUserNotFound(err)`.

A way to do it in your code is to treat the cases that you wish to consider. It could be something like

```
if err != nil {
    if auth.IsCertificateFetchFailed(err) {
        return errors.New("Certificate Fetch Failed")
    } else if auth.IsConfigurationNotFound(err) {
        return errors.New("Configuration Not Found")
    } else if auth.IsEmailAlreadyExists(err) {
        return errors.New("Email Already Exists")
    } // ...else if.. and so on, dependng on your needs and patience :)
    
    return err  // for any unmanaged case
}
```

Of course, you may create a more generic function on this pattern.

Frankly I would have preferred a simpler solution, like being able to somehow cast to a Firebase error, but that's life and this is what the SDK provides.

It's also ironic that the fathers/mothers of Firebase expose the error codes in .Net, but not in their own programming language :)

I hope this helps.